# Move page title using local xml - only on Homepage

Tags: magento-1.8, local.xml

i would like to unset the pagetitle only on the Homepage of Magento. The Answer on how to unset on all pages i found in here: [Move page title using local xml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4240/move-page-title-using-local-xml)
But how do i need to write the local.xml to only remove the pagetitle on the Homepage?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve it.
 Edit the `home page` from `CMS >> Pages` and either 
 
 click the Content tab and empty the `content header` field
 
Or
 click the Design tab and enter the following text in  `layout update xml`

```
<cms_page>
    <reference name="content">
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <name>page_content_heading</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
</cms_page>
```

and save